# SSRS Report date parameter values using SSAS Cube as datasource - Grey out unavailable values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssas, reportparameter

i m building an SSRS report using SSAS cube as the data source. The report contains shared data-sets which provide the required data. below is the set up.

- Sql server version : Sql server 2008R2
- Report builder 3.0

I have, Report A, powered by Dataset D, running on Cube C. The dataset has 3 parameters out of which one of them is a date parameter- P1. I have it set up such that on the report there is  another parameter - P2 which contains the type as Date ( to ensure the user is exposed to a date picker), the input from this, P2 is then manipulated to required format before fed into the dataset parameter P1 (hidden). I have two questions regarding this parameter.

Currently, when the user pick's a date (P2) which has no values, the report errors out as it doesn't find that corresponding member on the cube. Can it be made such that if the member doesn't exists, a simple error message like "date not found" pops up as opposed to report failing?

Secondly, can i manipulate the date picker (P2) exposed to the user such that the unavailable dates are grey'ed out on the date parameter (P2)?

Please let me know if there is any more info required on each of the questions.

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried limiting the Available Values of the date parameter?

Comment: When i tried limiting the available values, using a dataset which had the list of dates, it threw datatype error. The dataset also was powered from Cube and i had formatted the output to datetime format as well.

Comment: Try using a straight SQL query to limit the available values, so you can return a DateTime datatype and not just a datetime formatted string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tab Alleman, but i m a little confused as to where you suggested using a straight sql query? I tried creating a dataset with straight sql listing out the available dates and then feeding that as an input to the parameter however, on doing that the Date picker goes away and a list of available dates appear. My objective was to have the date picker and just grey out the unavailable ones.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't possible in SSRS.  We don't have any ability to control the date picker.  As for handling the error when an invalid date is sent, I would handle it in a SQL proc that wraps my MDX, but you can also try error handling in the report:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154047.aspx   Good luck!